# Django. No module named reportlab.pdfgen

Tags: python, django, django-admin, reportlab

I get such error in my django website

```
Exception Value: No module named reportlab.pdfgen
```

In my local linux environment it works. Is there any way to fix it?

[you can see this problem here](http://sghsgh.idl.pl/admin/)

Comment: Such ? Tell how you install reportlab.? You are using DEBUG=True in production.? Why.?

Comment: I haven't installed reportlab in my local linux enviroment and it works local. How can I do it in my hosting? Debug = True because I would like to find problems right now :)

Comment: Oh. You didn't installed & checked in `local` then how come that code gonna work in `Production`.? Actually the way is please logged into production `bash` and install everything or find a way to install in production. And if you want to check then go to `python manage.py shell` and type `import reportlab` if that's work then surely if your code too.

Comment: In my local environment It works without additional installation. How can I install it on my hosting server? I have no admin rights.  I can only get to ftp files.

Comment: You didn't mention the hosting service provider.? `PaaS` or `Shared` or `VM` ?

Answer (score 5):

Try installing `reportlab` using `pip`:

```
pip install reportlab
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with `sudo apt-get install python-reportlab`